# load large amount of data in asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net

I have a table in SQL Server which contains more than 12000 rows. When I load all the rows into an asp.net web page it takes 10 to 15 minutes to load all the rows.

Please help me loading data in seconds..

Comment: Simple: **don't** load all the rows at once! Use server-side paging - only load 10, 50, 100 rows at once - the user cannot handle more than that anyway.

Comment: take a look at IIS compression http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003(WS.10).aspx like marc_s said, no one likes to read  that much data at once. if users really want them all, offer them a download instead.

Comment: Yes you are right.. Actually i was doing that because i wanted to search data in all the records and i was using row filter of dataset for searching in current loaded items. But now i got it ..load top 100 records and search record by passing query in a view state and search data in all the records of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the process is taking the most time? There are many distinct stages to this action:

1. Query execution time in SQL Server.
2. Transfer time from SQL Server to your data reader (ADO.NET? across a network?)
3. Binding the data to the grid in ASP.NET.
4. Transferring the rendered HTML to the client.

Only when you know *exactly* what is slow, can you properly optimise.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. You can use [qzip](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip). Apparently, it won't bring load times down to seconds. But you will see good improvements in load time.
2. Write an handler which returns results in set of 100's and display results using jQuery asynchronously as in Facebook, where when you move down, more stories are feed, you can do a similar thing for your website, or you can have a "Load More" button which does the same thing except the user has to press the "Load More" button instead.

Note: Implementing the above is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to find an third party grid control which have on-demand `virtual paging` support.